# What is the difference between Location and EffectiveURI?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, uri

I just created a bucket named `ghazals-ghulam-ali` on `AWS` and in return I got 2 URL's:

```
Location : http://ghazals-ghulam-ali.s3.amazonaws.com/
EffectiveURI : https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ghazals-ghulam-ali
```

What is the difference between `Location` and `EffectiveURI`? How both are useful to me?

I created the bucket using `AWS PHP SDK` as follows:

```
public function create_bucket($user_id) {
    try {
        $this->s3Client = new S3Client($this->options);
        $isBucketCreated = $this->s3Client->createBucket(array(
                'Bucket' => _global::bucketNamePrecursor.$user_id
        ));
    }catch(Exception $exc){
        $isBucketCreated = false;
    }

    return $isBucketCreated;
}
```

Value for `echo $isBucketCreated`: (bucketName : ghazals-noor-jahan)

```
{ "Location": "http:\/\/ghazals-noor-jahan.s3.amazonaws.com\/", "@metadata":
{ "statusCode": 200, "effectiveUri": "https:\/\/s3-us-west-
2.amazonaws.com\/ghazals-noor-jahan", "headers": { "x-amz-id-2":   
"BSf4Q230WqUe4ZRXviiSSdFH76SW7VMW1qNAFv2PUhyZ1qkrcMabTIh
lRLVVMHiHK9Yv4n7ZFVA=", "x-amz-request-id": "CEDA84E8E932AB7B", "date": "Mon, 
08 Feb 2016 13:16:34 GMT", "location": "http:\/\/ghazals-noor-
jahan.s3.amazonaws.com\/", "content-length": "0", "server": "AmazonS3" } } }
```

Comment: Just looking at the values, they are both potentially useful, but I will hesitate to explain further for the moment, because my answer would be partially speculative since I am unclear where the two pieces of information are coming from.  This question is interesting because I'm not familiar with `EffectiveURI` being a concept in the S3 API.  What are you using to create the bucket -- the AWS php SDK? (version?)  Or another library?  Will you edit the question to show the code you're using to create the bucket and the output it is generating?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Edited the question.

Comment: Great, thanks.  Now, the output data structures you dumped from `$isBucketCreated`?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Added the raw json

Answer (score 0):

The location is the global reference to the bucket you created and what is used in some API connections to the bucket in question as well as connecting to the bucket from a browser. The effectiveURI meta is an internal meta which is passed to the PHP SDK and indicates the availability zone that the S3 bucket is hosted out of, however as S3 is a global service and S3 bucket names are required to be globally unique the location is what you use as it references the effective URI and eliminates the developers need to add the availability zone to the bucket URI as well.

For your purposes the only value you will care about in further programming and the only value of use to you will be the location value.